# Round double to number in interval, defining by step

Tags: java, double, rounding

I have some abstract double interval, defining by step f.e.:

`0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 - where interval == 0.1`

`0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 - where interval == 0.25`

`0.0, 0.5, 1.0 - where interval == 0.5`

Does Java have some instrument to "round" some double to closest number, according to interval? f.e:

`0.511111 - to 0.5` in first case

`0.599999 - to 0.6` in first case

`0.511111 - to 0.5` in second case

`0.599999 - to 0.5` in second case

`0.711111 - to 0.75` in second case

`0.744444 - to 0.5` in third case

`0.755555 - to 1.0` in third case

`0.92222 - to 1.0` in third case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Tschallacka, i not need round to n decimal places

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate.

Comment: But maybe you could use some information out of that answer. Have a look at RoundingMode and try to figure out, if you can implement your own RoundingMode? Not sure if that works though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java has instruments which can round numbers to n decimal places, see [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java). For rounding to any interval you specified, you may have to manually use `Math.round`.

**Formula:**

Given an interval `r` and a double value `x` to round, a simple formula is:

- `x_rounded = Math.round(x/r)*r;`

**Examples:**

```
double x = 0.59999;
double r = 0.25; // Quarters
x = Math.round(x/r)*r;
System.out.println(x); // Result is 0.5

double x = 0.59999;
double r = 0.1; // Tenths
x = Math.round(x/r)*r;
System.out.println(x); // Result is approximately 0.6

double x = 0.31421;
double r = 0.125; // Eighths
x = Math.round(x/r)*r;
System.out.println(x); // Result is exactly 0.375
```

**Proof:**

- The interval `r` can be thought as the value of a fractional unit.

  - When `r = 0.25`, the fractional unit is a quarter.
- The value `x/r` represents the number of fractional units that make up `x`.

  - When `x = 0.75`, `r = 0.25`, `x/r == 3`, because `x` contains three fractional unit, which is the quarter. `x/r` represents the number of quarters.
- `Math.round(x)` rounds `x` to the nearest integral value. Similarly, `Math.round(x/r)` rounds `x/r` to the nearest integral multiple of that fraction.

  - For `x = 0.7, r = 0.25`, we have `x/r = 2.8`, representing 2.8 quarters. `Math.round(x/r)` therefore rounds the value to the nearest quarter, 3 quarters.
- `Math.round(x/r)*r` therefore rounds `x` to the nearest fractional interval `r`. The multiplier is needed because `r` is the value of each fractional unit.

  - For `x = 0.7, r = 0.25`, `Math.round(x/r)` represents 3 quarters. It has to be multiplied by `r=0.25` to get the rounded value of `x`.

Comment: ok, round please 0.7333333 in interval 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 (step 0.25) with such algorithm. it must be 0.5

Comment: Invervals 0.0 cannot work. However I got 0. For 0.25, I got 0.75. For 0.5 I got 0.5. For 0.75 I got 0.75. For 1.0 I got 1.

Comment: Precision `0.0` is correct to return `0` as: Divide by zero results a `NotANumber` value, which multiplied by zero, gives `0` as result...

Answer (score 2):

Use `BigDecimal` and [`setScale()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-int-) to round.

However it will not work with the `0.25` precision, but you might do a workaround, something like this:

```
public BigDecimal round( BigDecimal value, BigDecimal precision )
{
   return value.divide(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
               .round(BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
               .multiply(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```