# Rounding to multiples of 5

Tags: java, rounding, currency

I'd like make my program to be even more precise and to consider that there aren't coins for 1,2,7 values (only 5,10,20,50,100..), so there is a rule called rounding to five forints.

Example:

```
111,112  -> 110 
113,114  -> 115
116,117  -> 115
118,119  -> 120
```

My question is which function should I use in JAVA to reach my goal and get the right rounded value?

Comment: You could write your own function

Comment: Write your own, cause the logic is fare from common rounding (ceil, floor, round, i mean)

Comment: The base formula is: b = round(a / 5) * 5

Comment: @Essigwurst Be careful of int division! This is Java

Comment: "aren't coins for 1,2,7 values" I don't understand, and I feel like the problem is slightly understated.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem if you actually need to turn this into change.

Comment: Ok not quite duplicate of [Round double to number in interval, defining by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580602/round-double-to-number-in-interval-defining-by-step) - this deals with `double` instead of `int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write it this way:

```
int roundTo5(int value)
{
    return ((value + 2) / 5) * 5;
}
```

This takes any forint value, adds 2 and divides by 5. This makes a "floor rounding" of integers and multiplies 5 again.

```
0 → 2 → 0 → 0
1 → 3 → 0 → 0
2 → 4 → 0 → 0
3 → 5 → 1 → 5
4 → 6 → 1 → 5
5 → 7 → 1 → 5
6 → 8 → 1 → 5
7 → 9 → 1 → 5
8 → 10 → 2 → 10
9 → 11 → 2 → 10
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following method.

```
public static int roundTo5(int n) {
        int t = n % 10; // get modulo 10 of n
        switch (t) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            // result will be n - n%10;
            return n - t;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            // result will be n - n %10 + 5
            return n - t + 5;
        case 8:
        case 9:
            // result will be n - n%10 + 10;
            return n - t + 10;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this isn't concise, it's extremely readable and provably correct. +1

Comment: But could be specified as %5 instead.

Comment: thanks Ryan for the suggetion.  I have modified the method  to public static int roundTo5(int n) {

  int t = n % 5; // get modulo 5 of n
  switch (t) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 2:
   // result will be n - n%5 ;
   return n - t;
  case 3:
  case 4:
   // result will be n - n%5 + 5
   return n - t + 5;
  }
  return 0;
 } .  This also provides the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**Say a is your integer or float you want to round** :

```
int round = Math.round( ((float)(a)/5) * 5);
```

if you declare as a float you can skip the type casting.

Comment: This will give a value of 0 for 4 (if `a` is integer). Also, there is an extra parenthesis.

Comment: ay yeah. done my testing with float numbers. a typecasting will do.

Comment: But it is quite a bad idea to use floats for currency values at the first place.

Comment: next time you buy a $7.67 product, you tell this to the cashier. xD

Comment: @FilliposChristou that is still an integer number (of cents)  though. Prices that are really more precise than the smallest coin for a currency are rare (one popular example are petrol prices here in Europe), but afaik the total still gets calculated using fixed-point math

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wasn't mentioned, but the following seems that should do the job well:

```
5 * (Math.round(n / 5))
```